# How to remove characters in string after email

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm using this code to list email addresses from a HTML page.

```
require 'nokogiri'

selector = "//a[starts-with(@href, \"mailto:\")]/@href"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse File.read 'in.rb'

nodes = doc.xpath selector

addresses = nodes.collect {|n| n.value[7..-1]}

puts addresses
```

This is sample code I'm parsing:

```
<a href="mailto:joe@example.com?subject=My Business Is Dying">
```

But I'm getting more than just the email address. I'm getting this in my results:

```
joe@example.com?subject=My Business Is Dying
```

How do I drop off everything after the question mark so it's only the email address?

Comment: `in.rb` is an HTML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always chop off anything after the `?` character:

```
addresses.map! do |address|
  address.sub(/\?.*/, '')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use one of these two:

```
str = 'joe@example.com?subject=My Business Is Dying'

str.split('?').first # => "joe@example.com"
str[/^[^?]+/] # => "joe@example.com"
```

The second is a simple regular expression embedded in [String's `[]` (slice) method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D). The pattern basically says "start at the beginning and grab everything up until a question mark."

They're equivalent as far as speed goes. I'd probably use the first because it's easier to read.